# Внутри RecyclerView не работает прокрутка у отдельных айтемов

Tags: android, recyclerview

Имеется RecyclerView, один из типов item может быть с прокруткой NestedScrollView. Но почему то этот айтем не прокручивается, т.е не работает NestedScrollView. Подскажите в чем может быть причина ?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Comment: К сожалению не помогло.